# Iterate over a list of objects and return a child list if condition is met

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a cleaner way to iterate over a list of things and return the list of stuff if a condition is met without needing to iterate over the list twice?

Please see the code below.

```dart
void main() {
  final x = [Stuff("a"), Stuff("b")];
  final y = [Stuff("x"), Stuff("y")];
  final things =  [Thing(x), Thing(y)];
  
final res =  things.where((thing) => thing.stuffs.any((x) => x.x == 'y')).first;
  print(res.stuffs);
  // return list y [Stuff("x"), Stuff("y")]
}

class Thing{
  List<Stuff> stuffs;
  Thing(this.stuffs);
}

class Stuff{
  String x;
  Stuff(this.x);
}
```

I can use this to find the correct Thing object, but then I still have to iterate over the list of stuff to find the correct list.

```dart
final res1 = things.where((thing) => thing.stuffs.any((x) => x.x == 'y')).first;
```

Comment: Your current implementation does not iterate over the list twice. The [where](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method returns a lazy iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, no dramatic change but a little bit cleaner:

```
final res = things.firstWhere(
  (thing) => thing.stuffs.any((x) => x.x == 'y'),
);
```